# Is it possible to populate a record using a list in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, types, record

If I have a record like so:

```
data EdgeSet = EdgeSet {
    top :: Int,
    right :: Int,
    bottom :: Int,
    left :: Int,
} deriving (Show)
```

Is it possible to populate the properties via a list of matching type?

I'm chasing something along the lines of:

```
...
where
    edgeList = [1, 2, 3, 4]
    edgeSet = EdgeSet {edgeList}
```

If not, any ideas on how I could be a little more succinct than what I currently have?

```
EdgeSet {top=edgeList !! 0, left=edgeList !! 1, bottom=edgeList !! 2, right=edgeList !! 3}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're confident that the list you use will always have exactly 4 elements, then as often with Haskell, pattern matching is the nicest, most readable option:

```
edgeSet = let [a, b, c, d] = edgeList in EdgeSet a b c d
```

which you could easily extract into a function if you needed to reuse it.

Note that, as I implied, this will crash if given a list of length less than four - but then so will the solution you gave. (Actually yours will work on lists of length 5 or more whereas mine won't - but you can easily adjust the pattern to cope with that if you care.)

I'm not aware that Haskell offers any nicer syntax for doing this. I would advise reconsidering whether you need a list at all - it will probably be easier and more idiomatic to just feed the data directly into the `EdgeSet` constructor rather than going through a list. This obviously depends in part on how you're getting that data in the first place.

Also note that a 4-tuple is much more type safe than a list if you are sure you will only ever have 4 elements, because the compiler will then make sure you have the correct number.

Answer (score 2):

I can't think of anything shorter than

```
where
    -- given
    edgeList = [1, 2, 3, 4]
    -- split into components and call the constructor
    [x1,x2,x3,x4] = edgeList
    edgeSet = EdgeSet x1 x2 x3 x4
```

Maybe there is some Generic helper in the libraries for this, but I am not aware of any such thing.

Note that the code above will crash your program at runtime if `edgeList` is not four elements long. If the list origin is not trusted, you might want to validate the list instead, e.g. using `case of` and handle the unexpected length more gracefully.

Answer (score 1):

Might not be what you're looking for but could always do something along the lines of:

```
module EdgeSet where

data EdgeSet = EdgeSet {
  top :: Int,
  right :: Int,
  bottom :: Int,
  left :: Int
} deriving (Show)

class ListToMyClass a where
  fromListToClass :: [Int] -> a

instance ListToMyClass EdgeSet where
  fromListToClass [a,b,c,d] = EdgeSet a b c d
```

You have to know the list will be length 4.

Comment: It feels like premature abstraction to me to make this a typeclass rather than just use an ad hoc function `[Int] -> EdgeSet`

Comment: I agree with you just showing another option in the event that this is something they'd like to do with other classes